# How do I remove trailing \ from %~p in a For command?

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

I have a Windows batch file that uses the following command

```
for /r %%i in (dir) do @echo %server%%%~pi>>%filename%
```

where %server% is network location of the folder (other users use different drive mappings) and %filename% is the text file I am storing the results in (done this way for debugging purposes).

The folders getting listed in the file end up with a trailing backslash, that seems to be causing some issues when the file is read.  How can I get rid of the trailing backslashes, without manually editing the created file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the directory name (with the trailing backslash) to a normal variable, and then echo it with substring variable expansion of 0,-1 to exclude the final character, all in a command list in the for-loop body:

```
for /r %%i in (dir) do @(set d=!server!%%~pi& echo !d:~0,-1!) >>!filename!
```

Here's the help on substring variable expansion from `help set`:

> May also specify substrings for an expansion.
>
> ```
> %PATH:~10,5%
> ```
>
> would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
>   characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded
>   result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to the
>   remainder of the variable value.  If either number (offset or length) is
>   negative, then the number used is the length of the environment variable
>   value added to the offset or length specified.
>
> ```
> %PATH:~-10%
> ```
>
> would extract the last 10 characters of the PATH variable.
>
> ```
> %PATH:~0,-2%
> ```
>
> would extract all but the last 2 characters of the PATH variable.

Note that for this to work, you *must* enable `enabledelayedexpansion` and use the `!` delimiter for the variable in the for-loop body, to ensure that it expands during loop processing, rather than during parsing of the loop. I also changed `%filename%` to `!filename!`, because it's good practice to always enable and use this feature, even when it's not essential.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Such a simple task, but the answer eluded me.

Comment: Nothing is simple in Dosbatch. ;)

Comment: You will run into problems if a path contains the `!` character. This can be solved by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop. But there is a [better solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28163790/1012053).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to append a dot and use a 2nd FOR loop to get the normalized path, name, and extension:

```
for /r %%i in (dir) do for %%F in ("%%~pi.") do echo %server%%%~pnxF>>%filename%
```

One big advantage is this does not require delayed expansion, so you don't have to worry about paths with `!` getting corrupted when the FOR variable is expanded.